# How does the Linux kernel manage data that has been passed to a user program via DMA?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, dma

I was reading that in some network drivers it is possible via DMA to pass packets directly into user memory. In that case, how would it be possible for the kernel's TCP/IP stack to process the packets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that it doesn't. Data isn't going to be processed in more than one location at once, so if networking packets are passed directly to a user space program, then the kernel isn't going to do anything else with them; it has been bypassed. It will be up to the user space program to handle it.

An example of this was presented in a device drivers class I took a while back: High-Frequency stock trading. There is an article about one such implementation at [Forbes.com](http://www.forbes.com/sites/quora/2014/01/07/what-is-the-technology-stack-like-behind-a-high-frequency-trading-platform/). The idea is that traders want their information as fast as possible, so they use specially crafted packets that when received (by equally specialized hardware), they are presented directly to the traders program, bypassing the relatively high-latency TCP/IP stack in the kernel. Here's an excerpt from the linked article talking about two such special network cards:

> Both of these cards provide kernel bypass drivers that allow you to send/receive data via TCP and UDP in userspace. Context switching is an expensive (high-latency) operation that is to be avoided, so you will want all critical processing to happen in user space (or kernel-space if so inclined).

This technique can be used for just about any application where the latency between user programs and the hardware needs to be minimized, but as your question implies, it means that the kernel's normal mechanisms for handling such transactions are going to be bypassed.

Comment: @SLawaon, but the question was not how to add DMA in a driver; I was rather curious how will the IP stacl be able to handle ingress packets, if they would've been placed in the user memory by DMA, since tcp/ip works with kernel memory.

Comment: Ah... you're asking how the *kernel* deals handles TCP/IP packets if they have been they have been... for lack of a better term, "given" to a userspace program via some shared DMA buffer because this would essentially bypass the kernel's processing of the packet. Is this correct? I thought your question was asking how *you* could get at the DMA buffers from userspace.

Comment: Correct, that's what I'm trying to understand. I'm thinking that in network drivers it's unlikely to DMA packets right to the user space and bypass tcp/ip stack altogether. It'd more suitable in, for instance, video processing software.

Comment: @Mark I've changed my answer completely based on your comments. Let me know if I missed anything.

Answer (score 1):

Networking chip can have register entries that can filter out per IP/UDP/TCP + port and routes those packets to via special set DMA descriptors.    If you pre-allocate the DMA able memory via driver and MMAP that memory to user space, one can easily route a particular stream of traffic to user space completely without any kernel code touching it.

I used to work on a video platform.  The networking ingress is done by FPGA.  Once configured, it can route 10 gbits of UDP packets into the system and automatically route certain MPEG PS PID matched packets out to CPU.    It can filter some other video/audio packets into the other part of system at 10gbits wire speed in a very low end FPGA.